# How to abstract the intersection of types in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I'm new to TypeScript and I'm trying to write a generic function which returns the intersection of two types.

I don't I'm quite understanding record types and their intersection very well so I'm probably doing something wrong but here goes...

Let's say we have some types like these:

```js
type A = { foo: string }
var a: A = { foo: 'foo' }

type B = { [key: string]: string }
var b: B = a

interface C { foo: string }
var c: C = a

type D = { bar: number }
var d: D = { bar: 123 }

type E = { [key: string]: number }
var e: E = d

interface F { bar: number }
var f: F = d

type G = A & D
var g: G = { ...a, ...d }
g = { ...c, ...f }

type H = A & D
var h: H = { ...a, ...d }
h = { ...c, ...f }

type I = B & E
var i: I = { ...b, ...e } // Error!... >_<
i = { ...a, ...d } // Error!
i = { ...c, ...f } // Error!

type I2 = { [key: string]: string & number }
var i2: I2 = {} // Can only be empty
i = i2

type J = C & F
var j: J = { ...c, ...f }
j = { ...a, ...d }

type K = { [key: string]: string | number }
var k: K = { ...a, ...d }
k = { ...b, ...e }
k = { ...c, ...f }
```

Now the problem I was actually trying to solve was this:

```js
const func1 = <T, U>(t: T, u: U, f: (t: T, u: U) => T & U): T & U => {
    return f(t, u)
}

h = func1(a, d, (t, u) => ({ ...t, ...u }))
i = func1(b, e, (t, u) => ({ ...t, ...u })) // Error
j = func1(c, f, (t, u) => ({ ...t, ...u }))
```

And the workaround that I came up with:

```js
type RecordIntersection<T, U> = { [C in (keyof T | keyof U)]: T[keyof T] | U[keyof U] }

const func2 = <T, U>(t: T, u: U, f: (t: T, u: U) => RecordIntersection<T, U>): RecordIntersection<T, U> => {
    return f(t, u)
}

h = func2(a, d, (t, u) => ({ ...t, ...u })) // Error
k = func2(b, e, (t, u) => ({ ...t, ...u }))
j = func2(c, f, (t, u) => ({ ...t, ...u })) // Error
```

This works for my particular use case but I only get type `K` back for everything.

Playing around some more and I can get this to work:

```
type Intersection<T, U> = keyof T extends keyof U ? RecordIntersection<T, U> : T & U

const func3 = <T, U>(t: T, u: U, f: (t: T, u: U) => Intersection<T, U>): Intersection<T, U> => {
    return f(t, u)
}

h = func3(a, d, (t, u) => ({ ...t, ...u }))
k = func3(b, e, (t, u) => ({ ...t, ...u }))
j = func3(c, f, (t, u) => ({ ...t, ...u }))
```

I can't seem to do much with a `RecordIntersection<T, U>` as I can't work out how to get either a `T` or `U` back out. See [How to use conditional types to filter unions in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58247549/367796).

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your preamble is a bit confusing to me .. for something to be assignable to an intersection it must satisfy both constituents of the intersection, this means that sometimes you create intersections that are not instantiable with anything, such as an intersection between an object with a string  indexer that returns number and a string indexer that returns string. Also having a clear example from start to finish with what you expect and what you get, would be very helpful to anyone trying to answer this question.

Comment: I have simplified the question and extracted the other implied questions to their own posts.